# jquery ajax not creating golang session cockie

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ajax

I am creating an creating login part for with preact, jquery and golang. I am using chrome for testing. The login API works fine with testing by postman written in golang. Here is code for this part

```
e.Use(session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))))
//e.Use(xrayWrapper("bonusapi"))

e.POST("/login", func(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)
    sess.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   86400 * 7,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }

    if(sess.Values["auth"] == true){
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Already Login")
    }else {
        fmt.Println(sess.Values["auth"])
    }

    if(c.FormValue("password") == "admin" && c.FormValue("username") == "admin"){
        sess.Values["auth"] = true
        sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())
        fmt.Println(sess.Values["auth"])
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Login session start")
    }else {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Forbidden Access")
    }

    //return c.String(http.StatusOK, )
})
```

But it does not work when I use ajax request with jquery. I mean session cookies does do not work in ajax request. I am not sure what is the problem with it. Anyone can help, please. Here is my ajax request code which has a problem I think

```
var username = props["path"][6].getElementById("username").value.trim();
    var password = props["path"][6].getElementById("password").value.trim();
    var credentials = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }

    var _this = this
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/login", 
        data:credentials
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing ajax headers [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials)

For cross-domain scenario, 3 things need to happen:

- Client needs to set `withCredentials=true` for the xhr object
- Set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` both in the OPTIONS preflight request as well as the actual request
- Set the cookie as needed

> The most interesting capability exposed by both XMLHttpRequest or
>   Fetch and CORS is the ability to make "credentialed" requests that are
>   aware of HTTP cookies and HTTP Authentication information. **By default,
>   in cross-site XMLHttpRequest or Fetch invocations, browsers will not
>   send credentials.**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/login", 
    data:credentials,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
})
.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I got this error. Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:5000/login: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: @MuhammadShaaban does you server sent `CORS` headers? Looks like not.

Comment: I am using this line of echo golang in my api. e.Use(middleware.CORS())

Comment: It's unclear what is this line doing, does it set valid headers?

Comment: I think you solved main issue. I can resolve other. Thanks very much. I let you know soon